# C# thread safe closure inside foreach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote a code block, but I am not sure it is thread safe.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in result)
{
    var t = new Task(async () => 
    {
        int retries = 0;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            while (retries <= _maxRetries && !success)
            {
                await doSomething(kvp.Value);
                success = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            retries++;
        }

        if (retries == _maxRetries)
        {
            //TODO: need to do smth about it
        }
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
    t.Start();
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Can I rely on the fact that when the compiler sets the task he uses a safe 
value, meaning that as long as Im in the loop and the task haven't stated yet, the values set are ok?

Because, I think that after the first retry of the while loop, the `kvp` object won't be as he was when the task ran at first time.

If its in-fact not thread-safe, which I think it really isn't, how can it be fixed?

Comment: Which version of .NET is this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen im using .net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on C# 5, then your code is fine; the semantics of `foreach` have been changed such that the loop variable is logically scoped to each iteration. Per [Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/):

> In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time.

If you're on C# 4 or earlier, then you should copy `kvp` to a local variable for the closure.

Your code has an unrelated bug: A task initialized through the `Task` constructor will not wait for the completion of the asynchronous function delegate that is passed to it as argument. Instead, you should use `Task.Run` for such delegates.

There is a simpler (safe) way of achieving this:

```
var tasks = result.Select(kvp => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    int retries = 0;
    bool success = false;
    // ...
})).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: won't the local variable just use as a reference to the normal kvp?

Comment: @OriRefael: Yes, but the captured local variable will not be updated on subsequent iterations of the loop with references to *other* `KeyValuePair` instances.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to save kvp in local variable inside your task like this:

```
 var t = new Task(async () => 
    {
        var localKvp = kvp;
        ....
    }
```

This way it will catch local variable for each task

Comment: but it will just store a refrence to it because its an object, so it wont do anything..

Comment: @OriRefael Wrong, it will create a new *variable* which will be captured by the delegate instead of the loop variable. This new variable will be treated as "new" each time the loop iterates, so in effect you will have one such variable per iteration, whereas the loop variable will only exist once, for all the iterations. This was changed in latter C# versions.

Comment: it will be unique reference for each task that references to its kvp object